# matplotlib contourf plot adding an extra step size in levels

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, colorbar, contourf

I'm trying to plot contourf of 7 clusters with min value in array of 0 and max of 6. However, when I plot it, there is an extra step size in the plot (the color pink outlining the brown cluster.Even though the colorbar labeled the pink as 5, it isn't supposed to be there so I'm not sure where it came from since label 5 is for the brown cluster and so on.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/494tU.png)

```
plt.clf() #clear figure before
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=100.0, globe=None))
ax.set_extent([96,105,1,8]) # lon_left, lon_right, lat_below, lat_upper
ax.gridlines(linewidths=0.01, draw_labels=True, alpha= 0.3)
ax.xlocator = mticker.FixedLocator(np.arange(96.,105.,0.5))
ax.ylocator = mticker.FixedLocator(np.arange(1.,8.,0.5))

clevs = np.arange(0,7,1)
cs = ax.contourf(coords[0], coords[1], code_recons[0], vmin=0, vmax=6, cmap="Accent", transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines("50m") # avail:110m, 50m, 10m..... '10m' is better resolution than default

cb = plt.colorbar(cs)
n_clusters=7
tick_locs = (np.arange(n_clusters) + 0.5)*(n_clusters-1)/n_clusters
cb.set_ticks(tick_locs)
cb.set_ticklabels(np.arange(n_clusters))

plt.show()
```

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Contourf has a *levels* argument.  If you don’t specify it, it will make 10 levels.

Comment: when i specify the levels arg, one of the clusters do not appear in the plot though...

Comment: specify the levels so they _bracket_ the data, not fall right on the data...  So if you have 1, 2,3, set the levels to 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5

Comment: I see...I didn't know that before and finally the extra color in colorbar and plot is gone and I learn something new today. Thank you so much!